# How to write a ternary statement which if true returns a string with a colon at the start

Tags: javascript

I want to write a ternary statement which if true returns a string with a colon at the start, e.g. 'Desk One: Test booking' else I just want to return the desk name, e.g. 'Desk One'.

Currently my ternary looks like this
`${deskName} ${bookingName ? bookingName : ''}`

I have tried the following with no success

`${deskName} ${bookingName ? ':'bookingName : ''}`
`${deskName} ${bookingName ? \":\"bookingName : ''}`

Comment: The JavaScript string concatenation operator is `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did was almost what you needed, here:

```
${bookingName ? `:${bookingName}` : ''}
```

You could also do:

```
${bookingName ? ':' + bookingName : ''}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to conditionally add a `:` before the contents of `bookingName`, if it isn't empty, otherwise, just add a empty string

```js
const deskName = 'Desk One'
let bookingName = 'Test booking';

console.log(deskName + (bookingName ? `: ${bookingName}` : ''));
// Desk One: Test booking

bookingName = '';
console.log(deskName + (bookingName ? `: ${bookingName}` : ''));
// Desk One
```